# IP Addresses on a DNS server system

Tags: networking, dns, ip, ip-address, ipv4

Which of the following IPv4 addresses could be set on a DNS server system?

```
127.0.0.1
193.231.20.1
192.168.2.2
255.255.255.0
```

What am I thinking is that the first ip address is the "loopback address" and I'm not sure if that could be set on dns, the third one is a private one so I'm not sure. I only think that the third one is good for that but I'm not sure about the other ones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first three addresses can be used; the fourth usually isn't an address at all.

- 127.0.0.1 is indeed a "loopback" address, but that does not prevent it from being used for services – in a way that's what it is *for*. (It's common to have DNS servers listen on loopback in addition to other addresses, and sometimes a DNS resolver is installed specifically to be used by the local host only.)
- 193.231.20.1 is a regular "global" address belonging to RoEduNet. There is actually a real DNS server running on that address.
- 192.168.2.2 is a regular "private" address (RFC 1918) allocated for use in LANs.
- 255.255.255.0 can mean two things:

  - 99.999% of the time, "addresses" starting with "255." aren't IP addresses at all – they specify *netmasks* used for subnets and routing.

    So if this comes from a homework question, then I'm quite sure you are supposed to say that 255.255.255.0 cannot be used – the intent is usually to make you recognize the odd item (a netmask among host addresses).
  - But it can *also* mean an actual IP address from the so-called "Class E" range (240.0.0.0/4). This range was reserved for "future use" long ago, so most software was written to outright reject such addresses – however, some operating systems (e.g. Linux) *can* use them as regular IP addresses (and even host a DNS service). Nobody sane does, though.